# Is there a way to see who upvoted me?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, up-votes

I'm just curious on some of my questions, if I get a high enough reputation, will I be abl eto see who upvoted or downvoted me? I know I can see open and close votes, but can I see up and down votes?

Comment: Official answer on the subject: only devs and people with database access can see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90735/can-admins-see-who-downvoted-them-if-not-do-developers-with-db-access-look-it/90758#90758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, nobody (not even mods that I'm aware of) gets to see who votes in what way.

Comment: THX xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: The way it should be. :)

Comment: Rfusca, mods can see detailed voting patterns (subject to some limitations on minimum numbers of votes).  Because I don't know how well protected the procedure is, rather than describing it here, may I suggest you inquire over at [Teachers' Lounge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge)?

Comment: @whuber we can see patterns and such, but not specifics of who voted on a certain question.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90735/can-admins-see-who-downvoted-them-if-not-do-developers-with-db-access-look-it/90758#90758

Comment: @rf Your response shows me the question is ambiguous.  At one place, the OP does not appear to be asking about any "certain question," because you (as a mod) *can* see "who upvoted and downvoted" anybody on the site whenever those totals are 5 or greater.  But if "on some of my questions" means at the level of detail of a *single* question, then you're right: only developers can see that.